# How would I make just the button collapse the section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Right now I am using this accordion buttom on several spots on my webpage. Currently, when it is open, if you click anywhere inside the accordion, it collapses. I want to make it so that just the top part of the accordion, the actually button part, collapses it so that I can add in links and other things to the accordion content.
https://jsfiddle.net/nc4euge3/

Here is some code because it can't link to js fiddle without it :

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="accordion-button">
            <h3>
            <div class="accordion-marker"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div><span class="question">Thing #1</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <p>
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the + Thing 1 part to be hidden when text is clicked?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be hidden, it would be preferred if it stayed. I just want the user to click that to close it, rather than it closing if they accidentally click inside the drop down part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a small tweak there - listen to the click on button, not the whole accordion item.

Check demo - https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/nc4euge3/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $accordion = $('.accordion .accordion-item');
    $('.accordion-button').click(function () { /* change to the button */
        var $this = $(this).parent();  /* update to get the accordion item container */
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.removeClass('active').find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
        } else {
            $accordion.removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $accordion.find('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
            $this.find('i').addClass('fa-minus')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: YES! This is perfect. You are amazing. Who knew one small tweak would make that much of a difference. Certainly not me, thats for sure, haha

Comment: Sure, glad I helped ))